# Removing everything that isnt a to z

Tags: python

This is my program:

```
def count_occurances(lst):
    d = {}
    contents = lst #Filling the dictonary
    contents =  map(str, contents)
    for contents in lst:
        if contents not in d: #Adds every item
            d[contents] = 1 
        else:
            d[contents]=d[contents] +1 #Increases the value of the item if it already exists
    return d

listy_mc_listface = []
with open("\\Users\\saksa\\python_courses\\1DV501\\assign3\\eng_news_100K-sentences_B.txt", "r", encoding= 'utf-8') as f:
    string_name=f
    for line in string_name:
        for item in line:
            item = (item.lower())
            if (item.isalpha()) == True:
                listy_mc_listface.append(item)


freq = count_occurances(listy_mc_listface)
print (freq)
```

While isalpha removed most of the characters that I want to remove I see that there are still some chinese and arabic characters left. What is a better way to remove those and how would I implement it to my code? To clarify I only want to a to z, both capital and non-capital letters (since I already convert htem)

Comment: Regular expressions are what you're looking for: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: `import re; re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", your_string)` substitutes everything that is not in a-z or A-Z with an empty string. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @NiklasMertsch I tried using that method but I get: "xpected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: Then either convert your input to string or use bytes instead of strings for the patterns (`b"[^a-zA-]z"`, b"").